# Get the quantity and name of an object between related tables

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I'm taking data from my **Animals** table, which has a relationship with the **Categories** table. My problem is that I need to count how many products per category are registered.

Doing a search here on Stackoverflow, I started using the code below that is returning the quantity of animals per category ([Animal, quantity]).

```
$data = DB::table('animals')
                ->select(
                    DB::raw('category_id as category'),
                    DB::raw('count(*) as number'))
                ->groupBy('category')
                ->get();
            $array[] = ['Name', 'Quantity'];
            foreach($data as $key => $value)
            {

                $array[++$key] = [$value->category, $value->number];
            }
            $cat = json_encode($array);
            dd($cat);
```

Using "dd", I see that the data below is correct, but the category_id is coming, I am not sure how to get this id and put the category name for that id.

```
"[["Category","Quantity"],[1,10],[2,14],[3,30],[4,26],[5,1]]"
```

Example: [2,14] this refers to category_id 2 which has the name: **mammal**. So I would have 14 animals registered in the mammal category.

I would like the result to be like this:

```
"[["Category","Quantity"],[birds,10],[mammals,14],[reptiles,30],[amphibians ,26],[fish,1]]"
```

How can I handle this id related to the category name?

Comment: `DB::raw('category_name as category')`?

Comment: @u_mulder , no. The Animals table, has a field called category_id that stores the foreign key of the Category table

Comment: Then you need to join Category table and get name from there.

Answer (score 0):

Join your category table and get name from there, I suppose it should look like:

```
$data = DB::table('animals')
    ->join('category', 'animals.category_id', '=', 'category.id')
    ->select(
        DB::raw('category.id as category_id'),
        DB::raw('category.name as category_name'),
        DB::raw('count(*) as number'))
    ->groupBy('category')
    ->get();
```

[More about joins](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#joins)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method "withCount" from the model, it helps you to count the number of results from a relationship

```
$posts = App\Post::withCount('comments')->get();
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    echo $post->comments_count;
}
```

See the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models